# I want page to automatically include more posts when bottom on page is reached

Tags: php, javascript, css, infinite-scroll

As stated in title, I would like for more posts to show up when bottom of page is reached, right now there is a button where users can click and more posts will show, but when this happens the page is refreshed and goes back to top.

I have included image of how it currently lools like:

[image: Load]

Comment: Need to see some code. You will definitely need to use js, and load the new content via ajax.

Comment: this is called infinite scrolling, just so you know and can search for the correct term

Comment: Thanks Galen ill look into that, and the code is just a basic button code

Comment: Here's an automatic load, and check out the other demos. Shows you how to do it. Many others out there as jQuery and is the way to go: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html

Comment: another http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate

Comment: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html

Comment: D/L: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/ Demo: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/show-more-link-shortened-content/

Comment: I have tons of links, just search for them, you'll find many for `jQuery infinite scroll` or `jQuery read more`. Good luck, you'll enjoy learning jQuery. Cheers~

Comment: To add, most of the links I included here work with `IE7+ and FF`. I have to deal with both browsers. Just make sure you `test` in as many browsers as you can, `before publishing`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [jQuery appear plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/) to do this. Let's say you put the code that is run when the user clicks on your "Load More" button into a function called loadMore(). Then you'd create a DOM element (I use an empty div) with say an id of "foo", put in a bit of code:

```
$('#foo').appear(function() {
  loadMore();
});
```

and that should do what you need.

Comment: I have no clue how to use jquery, where would that go?
What would be in place of #foo